# Genetic algorithm libraries for Scala

Tags: scala, genetic-algorithm

Which are mature, maintained and flexible open source genetic algorithm (GA) libraries for Scala?

- *Mature* meaning that it is quite feature complete and bug free, ideally well documented.
- *Maintained* meaning that it is not an abandoned project, and it works fine with current the current (2.10) Scala version.
- *Flexible* meaning that it is fully configurable, I can plug in my own chromosome representations, fitness, breeding etc. functions, and it is generic and uses well Scala's type system.

Ideally on GitHub so it integrates best with my work flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main priority is maturity, I'd recommend [JGAP](http://jgap.sourceforge.net/), a library written in Java (which I used in my bachelor's with very successful results).

Using the natural interoperability between Java and Scala, there shouldn't be any problems about that. (But sure it would be great to see a Scala equivalent to it in terms of maturity and flexibility, taking advantage of Scala idioms)

About being maintained, it has not released new versions since 2009.

Sure there are other implementations out there but just wanted to add my 2¢ about a library I would sure revisit when the need comes (even if it is to start a port).

Comment: Yes, that's what I implied with the third condition (well adjusted to Scala's type system); but anyway thanks, I will have a look at JGAP.